# Android Emulator Network status

Tags: android

I want to check the network status of my emulator from command line. I have connected to the emulator console and used the following command "network status". But it gives me the following output "unknown command try help""
[CMD output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weeUQ.png)

Comment: try some UNIX commands such as ping, i think it is supported on Android

Answer (score 0):

You can use Connectivity service

```
root@generic_x86_64:/ # service call connectivity 1                         
Result: Parcel(
  0x00000000: 00000000 00000001 00000000 0000000d '................'
  0x00000010: 00000006 004f004d 00490042 0045004c '....M.O.B.I.L.E.'
  0x00000020: 00000000 00000003 0054004c 00000045 '........L.T.E...'
  0x00000030: 00000009 004f0043 004e004e 00430045 '....C.O.N.N.E.C.'
  0x00000040: 00450054 00000044 00000009 004f0043 'T.E.D.......C.O.'
  0x00000050: 004e004e 00430045 00450054 00000044 'N.N.E.C.T.E.D...'
  0x00000060: 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 '................'
  0x00000070: 00000009 006f0063 006e006e 00630065 '....c.o.n.n.e.c.'
  0x00000080: 00650074 00000064 0000000f 00700065 't.e.d.......e.p.'
  0x00000090: 002e0063 006d0074 0062006f 006c0069 'c...t.m.o.b.i.l.'
  0x000000a0: 002e0065 006f0063 0000006d          'e...c.o.m...    ')
```

or

```
root@generic_x86_64:/ # service call connectivity 5                            
Result: Parcel(
  0x00000000: 00000000 0000000c 00000001 00000000 '................'
  0x00000010: 00000001 00000006 004f004d 00490042 '........M.O.B.I.'
  0x00000020: 0045004c 00000000 00000004 00500047 'L.E.........G.P.'
  0x00000030: 00530052 00000000 00000009 004f0043 'R.S.........C.O.'
  0x00000040: 004e004e 00430045 00450054 00000044 'N.N.E.C.T.E.D...'
  0x00000050: 00000009 004f0043 004e004e 00430045 '....C.O.N.N.E.C.'
  0x00000060: 00450054 00000044 00000000 00000001 'T.E.D...........'
  0x00000070: 00000000 00000000 00000009 006f0063 '............c.o.'
  0x00000080: 006e006e 00630065 00650074 00000064 'n.n.e.c.t.e.d...'
  0x00000090: 0000000f 00700065 002e0063 006d0074 '....e.p.c...t.m.'
  0x000000a0: 0062006f 006c0069 002e0065 006f0063 'o.b.i.l.e...c.o.'
  0x000000b0: 0000006d 00000001 00000001 00000000 'm...............'
  0x000000c0: 00000004 00490057 00490046 00000000 '....W.I.F.I.....'
  0x000000d0: 00000000 00000000 0000000c 00490044 '............D.I.'
  0x000000e0: 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 'S.C.O.N.N.E.C.T.'
  0x000000f0: 00440045 00000000 0000000c 00490044 'E.D.........D.I.'
  0x00000100: 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 'S.C.O.N.N.E.C.T.'
  0x00000110: 00440045 00000000 00000000 00000001 'E.D.............'
  0x00000120: 00000000 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff '................'
  0x00000130: 00000001 00000002 00000000 0000000a '................'
  0x00000140: 004f004d 00490042 0045004c 004d005f 'M.O.B.I.L.E._.M.'
  0x00000150: 0053004d 00000000 00000000 00000000 'M.S.............'
  0x00000160: 0000000c 00490044 00430053 004e004f '....D.I.S.C.O.N.'
  0x00000170: 0045004e 00540043 00440045 00000000 'N.E.C.T.E.D.....'
  0x00000180: 0000000c 00490044 00430053 004e004f '....D.I.S.C.O.N.'
  0x00000190: 0045004e 00540043 00440045 00000000 'N.E.C.T.E.D.....'
  0x000001a0: 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 '................'
  0x000001b0: ffffffff ffffffff 00000001 00000003 '................'
  0x000001c0: 00000000 0000000b 004f004d 00490042 '........M.O.B.I.'
  0x000001d0: 0045004c 0053005f 00500055 0000004c 'L.E._.S.U.P.L...'
  0x000001e0: 00000000 00000000 0000000c 00490044 '............D.I.'
  0x000001f0: 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 'S.C.O.N.N.E.C.T.'
  0x00000200: 00440045 00000000 0000000c 00490044 'E.D.........D.I.'
  0x00000210: 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 'S.C.O.N.N.E.C.T.'
  0x00000220: 00440045 00000000 00000000 00000001 'E.D.............'
  0x00000230: 00000000 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff '................'
  0x00000240: 00000001 00000005 00000000 0000000c '................'
  0x00000250: 004f004d 00490042 0045004c 0048005f 'M.O.B.I.L.E._.H.'
  0x00000260: 00500049 00490052 00000000 00000000 'I.P.R.I.........'
  0x00000270: 00000000 0000000c 00490044 00430053 '........D.I.S.C.'
  0x00000280: 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 00440045 'O.N.N.E.C.T.E.D.'
  0x00000290: 00000000 0000000c 00490044 00430053 '........D.I.S.C.'
  0x000002a0: 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 00440045 'O.N.N.E.C.T.E.D.'
  0x000002b0: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 '................'
  0x000002c0: 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 00000001 '................'
  0x000002d0: 0000000a 00000000 0000000b 004f004d '............M.O.'
  0x000002e0: 00490042 0045004c 0046005f 0054004f 'B.I.L.E._.F.O.T.'
  0x000002f0: 00000041 00000000 00000000 0000000c 'A...............'
  0x00000300: 00490044 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 'D.I.S.C.O.N.N.E.'
  0x00000310: 00540043 00440045 00000000 0000000c 'C.T.E.D.........'
  0x00000320: 00490044 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 'D.I.S.C.O.N.N.E.'
  0x00000330: 00540043 00440045 00000000 00000000 'C.T.E.D.........'
  0x00000340: 00000001 00000000 00000000 ffffffff '................'
  0x00000350: ffffffff 00000001 0000000b 00000000 '................'
  0x00000360: 0000000a 004f004d 00490042 0045004c '....M.O.B.I.L.E.'
  0x00000370: 0049005f 0053004d 00000000 00000000 '_.I.M.S.........'
  0x00000380: 00000000 0000000c 00490044 00430053 '........D.I.S.C.'
  0x00000390: 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 00440045 'O.N.N.E.C.T.E.D.'
  0x000003a0: 00000000 0000000c 00490044 00430053 '........D.I.S.C.'
  0x000003b0: 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 00440045 'O.N.N.E.C.T.E.D.'
  0x000003c0: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 '................'
  0x000003d0: 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 00000001 '................'
  0x000003e0: 0000000c 00000000 0000000a 004f004d '............M.O.'
  0x000003f0: 00490042 0045004c 0043005f 00530042 'B.I.L.E._.C.B.S.'
  0x00000400: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000000c '................'
  0x00000410: 00490044 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 'D.I.S.C.O.N.N.E.'
  0x00000420: 00540043 00440045 00000000 0000000c 'C.T.E.D.........'
  0x00000430: 00490044 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 'D.I.S.C.O.N.N.E.'
  0x00000440: 00540043 00440045 00000000 00000000 'C.T.E.D.........'
  0x00000450: 00000001 00000000 00000000 ffffffff '................'
  0x00000460: ffffffff 00000001 0000000d 00000000 '................'
  0x00000470: 00000008 00490057 00490046 0050005f '....W.I.F.I._.P.'
  0x00000480: 00500032 00000000 00000000 00000000 '2.P.............'
  0x00000490: 0000000c 00490044 00430053 004e004f '....D.I.S.C.O.N.'
  0x000004a0: 0045004e 00540043 00440045 00000000 'N.E.C.T.E.D.....'
  0x000004b0: 0000000c 00490044 00430053 004e004f '....D.I.S.C.O.N.'
  0x000004c0: 0045004e 00540043 00440045 00000000 'N.E.C.T.E.D.....'
  0x000004d0: 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 '................'
  0x000004e0: ffffffff ffffffff 00000001 0000000e '................'
  0x000004f0: 00000000 00000009 004f004d 00490042 '........M.O.B.I.'
  0x00000500: 0045004c 0049005f 00000041 00000000 'L.E._.I.A.......'
  0x00000510: 00000000 0000000c 00490044 00430053 '........D.I.S.C.'
  0x00000520: 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 00440045 'O.N.N.E.C.T.E.D.'
  0x00000530: 00000000 0000000c 00490044 00430053 '........D.I.S.C.'
  0x00000540: 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 00440045 'O.N.N.E.C.T.E.D.'
  0x00000550: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 '................'
  0x00000560: 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 00000001 '................'
  0x00000570: 0000000f 00000000 00000010 004f004d '............M.O.'
  0x00000580: 00490042 0045004c 0045005f 0045004d 'B.I.L.E._.E.M.E.'
  0x00000590: 00470052 004e0045 00590043 00000000 'R.G.E.N.C.Y.....'
  0x000005a0: 00000000 00000000 0000000c 00490044 '............D.I.'
  0x000005b0: 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 'S.C.O.N.N.E.C.T.'
  0x000005c0: 00440045 00000000 0000000c 00490044 'E.D.........D.I.'
  0x000005d0: 00430053 004e004f 0045004e 00540043 'S.C.O.N.N.E.C.T.'
  0x000005e0: 00440045 00000000 00000000 00000001 'E.D.............'
  0x000005f0: 00000000 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff '................'
  0x00000600: 00000001 00000011 00000000 00000002 '................'
  0x00000610: 00370031 00000000 00000000 00000000 '1.7.............'
  0x00000620: 0000000c 00490044 00430053 004e004f '....D.I.S.C.O.N.'
  0x00000630: 0045004e 00540043 00440045 00000000 'N.E.C.T.E.D.....'
  0x00000640: 0000000c 00490044 00430053 004e004f '....D.I.S.C.O.N.'
  0x00000650: 0045004e 00540043 00440045 00000000 'N.E.C.T.E.D.....'
  0x00000660: 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 '................'
  0x00000670: ffffffff ffffffff                   '........        ')
```

Comment: Sorry, did not understand your suggestion. I just wants to check network status, network delay current net speed of the running emulator from the command line